# How to run an aleph program with Swi-prolog?

Tags: prolog

I’m trying to work Aleph with Swi-prolog. Are there any one could please tell me how to run this program if I have a file named train.pl (including the background and positive and negative examples.) What can I do to induce my program and get the output? By the way, I have already downloaded Aleph.pl for my program. When I ran it, it showed like this:
ERROR: c:/users/mac/downloads/aleph.pl:97:
        Wrong context: arithmetic_function/1 can only be used in a directive

Comment: Where is the aleph program?  What is in the line 97, and neighbour lines?

Comment: I downloaded the aleph.pl from this link ：http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/research/areas/machlearn/Aleph/aleph.pl

Comment: This is a program of 10,000+ lines, we are not going to debug it for you.  Produce https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to know I downloaded the Aleph from official website and why there are such errors? Where did you obtain the Aleph ?

Comment: I didn't. If you don't know if it is the official version, you better contact the author.

Comment: OK, cheers anyway .

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problems. However, after some googling, I found a [github repository](https://github.com/friguzzi/aleph) which contains the aleph script that actually works (`prolog/aleph.pl`). However, the manual could be more detailed (at least for a newbie like me). A minimal working example that I have managed to run is the trains example (`prolog/examples/train.pl`) and I did the following:

1. Put the `aleph.pl` script into some directory `path/to/dir`
2. Put the `train.pl` script into the same directory.
3. Executing the following commands, one by one:

   - `working_directory(_, 'path/to/dir').`
   - `consult('aleph.pl').`
   - `consult('trains.pl').`
   - `induce.`

I ignored some errors and warnings that have appeared when executing the command `consult('trains.pl').`:

```
ERROR: path/to/dir/train.pl:16:
ERROR:    source_sink `library(aleph)' does not exist
Warning: path/to/dir/train.pl:16:
Warning:    Goal (directive) failed: user:use_module(library(aleph))
```